# Use jquery and Flask to print input but print nothing

Tags: python, jquery, flask

I just learn flask to use with jquery, just want to print out what i typed in , but it print nothing

here is html code

```
    <body>
        <input id="name-input" type="text" />
        <button id="name-button">Submit Name</button>
        <p id="greeting"></p>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $("#name-button").click(function (event) {
                let message = {
                    name: $("#name-input").val()
                }
                $.post("http://10.0.0.4:5000/hello", JSON.stringify(message), function (response) {
                    $("#greeting").text(response.greeting);
                    console.log(response);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
```

here is flask code:

```
from flask import request
from flask import jsonify
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/hello',methods=['POST'])
def hello():
    message = request.get_json(force=True)
    name = message['name']
    response = {
        'greeting': 'Hello, ' + name + '!'
    }
    return jsonify(response)
```

when i click button, it print nothing!. please help, thank a lot

Comment: Did you look in your console tools to check that there is no error on the front end? e.g. F12 in Chrome

Comment: im not sure, it show no error in console window, if you can, can you use teamviewer to help me? please, i'm totally new, and i don't know exactly what going on   roganjosh

Comment: it print this `jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 POST http://10.0.0.4:5000/hello net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

Comment: Nope, there is no hope of that happening. You need a [mcve] and we can discuss it here

Comment: weird is my address is `http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/hello.html` but it print `http://10.0.0.4:5000/hello`

Comment: The first of them is `localhost` and the second is your local IP address on your network. You should be using the former in your jQuery

Comment: i followed this tutorial, even i copy the same code, but it still not print anything, in video tutorial, they use `http://10.0.0.4:5000/` but my is `127..` i dont know why they work but i'm not

Comment: hey , i think that my problem is use `http://10.0.0.4:5000/hello` at  <Script> post but it turn out that not where problem solved, i change to `http://127.0.0.1:5500/hello` but it not print result, `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)` is new error i get when change that

Comment: Why do you switch between port 5000 and 5500?

Comment: my bad, it 5000 both not 5500 ^^. but it still not running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues:

1. You're using the IP address shown in the example, which is very unlikely to point to your own PC on a network. More likely is `127.0.0.1:5000/hello`, which would be `localhost` if you're running through the dev server. You can actually run the server across the network by providing the `--host=0.0.0.0` flag to `flask run`. NOTE: This is only for the development server; you'll want to look at [deployment options](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/) when you run this for real
2. Your route only accepts POST requests, but you're sending a GET request

The HTMl:

```
<body>
    <input id="name-input" type="text" />
    <button id="name-button">Submit Name</button>
    <p id="greeting"></p>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("#name-button").click(function (event) {
            let message = {
                name: $("#name-input").val()
            }
            $.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/hello", JSON.stringify(message), function (response) {
                $("#greeting").text(response.greeting);
                console.log(response);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

The route:

```
@app.route('/hello',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello():
    message = request.get_json(force=True)
    name = message['name']
    response = {
        'greeting': 'Hello, ' + name + '!'
    }
    return jsonify(response)
```

Comment: when i use `flask run --host=0.0.0.0` it return `Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.` what that mean, and is this harmful?

Comment: i think it alway use production env , how can i fix this